# Adding free routing services in ArcGIS Web AppBuilder (developer)?

Tags: routing, arcgis-web-appbuilder, arcgis-portal

To add free routing services like openrouteservice or ORSM in WAB(developer) can we use the directions widget or do we have to develop a new widget for it?

Comment: Unless the services you mention conform to exactly the same URL syntax, parameters, functionality and output response as an Esri Network Analyst service, you'd need to build a new widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WAB directions widget is expecting to work with a NAServer web service compliant with ArcGIS specification.

If you are managing an ArcGIS Server of your own, you can build your own Network Dataset, using Network Analyst, and then publish a NAServer with a route solving method.

Comment: @harpinder I have this widget working with a ArcGIS NAServer published by a local municipality. I don't know in what your'e backing your info, but my experience tells me it does

Comment: Thanks ...It was done..i was using the URL without the webadaptor.